# Integrating paypal payflow with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal-rest-sdk

How can I integrate paypal payflow with rails. They have sdk available in java and .net Is there any gem for rails or any api calls for standard payment and recurring billing?

Answer (score 0):

We integrated paypal into our application using these gems:

- `https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-ruby`
- `https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK` this one has good documentation.

Folder with samples: `https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/tree/master/samples`

#### Updated:

From PayFlow documentation:

- The customer clicks Buy to purchase merchandise on your website.
- You request a secure token by passing a token ID to the Gateway server. [PayFlow doc related to tokens](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#secure-token)
- The Gateway server returns the secure token and your token ID to your website.
- You submit the secure token and token ID in an HTTP post to pages hosted on the Gateway server and redirect the customer's browser to the hosted pages. [documentation related to CC  form rendering](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#configuring-hosted-checkout-pages)
- The Gateway server uses the secure token to retrieve the amount and other transaction data.The customer submits their credit card number, expiration date, and other sensitive data directly to the host pages rather than to your website, easing your PCI compliance requirements.
- The Gateway processes the payment through the payment processing network.
- The Gateway server transparently returns the customer to the location on your website that you specified in the request to obtain a secure
  token. You display the results to the customer on your website.

Full guide is here: [guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide)

There is also a gist that may help you understand it from code perspective: [gist](https://gist.github.com/supairish/5872581)

Comment: I'm going through with paypal payflow documentation
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payflow/ but there it is mentioned that sdk available for .net and JAVA. So, I'm trying with API calls do you have any idea about that

Comment: @RebelRider I updated answer. I hope it will help you. If you find this helpful please mark it as solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'm using curl command to do the transaction in controller but when I use same credentials with additional parameters (for recurring) I'm getting user authentication failed for recurring in console. do you have any idea about this
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/recurring-billing/#using-the-sdk-to-perform-recurring-tasks

Comment: It's really hard to help you solve issues without seeing your code. Please update your question with curl command you use in controller and for recurring so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into ActiveMerchant. You can find your use case in the test folder of the gem.

https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/tree/master/test/remote/gateways

Comment: I'm going through with paypal payflow documentation
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payflow/ but there it is mentioned that sdk available for .net and JAVA. So, I'm trying with API calls do you have any idea about that. Active Merchant recurring is deprecated